# curl unexpected end of file when downloading gzip

Tags: downloads, tar, gzip

I used command

## The URL the data is located at.

URL=http://data.biostarhandbook.com/rnaseq/projects/griffith/griffith-data.tar.gz

## Downloading and unpack the data.

curl -s $URL | tar zxv
I got error
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Answer (score 2):

It works for me. Is it possible you have a bad network connection? Try to download the file first, and then unpack it, e.g.

```
wget http://data.biostarhandbook.com/rnaseq/projects/griffith/griffith-data.tar.gz
tar zxvf griffith-data.tar.gz && rm -f griffith-data.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same example you gave:

`curl -s http://data.biostarhandbook.com/rnaseq/projects/griffith/griffith-data.tar.gz | tar zxv`

and got it working correctly as seen here:

[image]

If this is still not working, it might be something blocking you from downloading it or having correct access to it.